# Serving files present externally of project in Node

Tags: node.js, http

I have a bunch of files present throughout my system say

```
file:///E:/Content/file.pdf
file:///E:/Content/Music/FL-Project.mp3
file:///D:/static/texts/random.txt
```

And i want these to be available through a node server with path like

```
http://localhost:3000/file.pdf
http://localhost:3000/FL-Project.mp3
http://localhost:3000/random.txt
```

How is this possible in node? I know express and various other tools are capable of doing this but from what I was able to explore its only possible for files inside project (or static). Note that I want to do this purely through a node script and only on these specific files so `http-server` is off the table too.

I'm expecting something like

```js
http.createServer(function onRequest (req, res) {
  someApi(
    req, 
    '/file.pdf',
    'file:///E:/Content/file.pdf'
  )
  // file as response
})
```

Comment: `Express.js`'s `static` middleware can serve static files out of the project root folder. For example, `app.use(express.static('..'))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use express for this. It make things a lot simple.

```js
const express = require('express')

var server = express()
server.use("/file.pdf", (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile("E:\\Content\\file.pdf")
})
server.listen(3000)
```

Note path is `E:\\Content\\file.pdf` and not `file:///E:/Content/file.pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

hi it is better you use nodejs web middlewares like [express](https://expressjs.com/). but for serving files with nodejs http server you can use this code :

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
      return;
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
```

Comment: Note that for this to work, you would have to run the script with a user that has read privileges for those files. This could be dangerous, as you might expose yourself to vulnerabilities

Comment: @Jason you are right it's better the user runs nodejs code, only have **read permission** to those files or directories

Comment: Is this code not complete? Also I'm okay if solution involves any new module. Doesn't strictly have to be `http`